# Could not instantiate Seam component: org.jboss.seam.core.ConversationIdGenerator

Tags: jboss, components, seam2

What could be the reason for the below exception? I have my persistence.xml and components.xml looks ok. Environment: JBoss EAP 6.3, Seam2 framework. I have successfully started the server when I have tried to access the url for my application I am receiving the following error message.

```
13:59:08,777 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/txo/amaster].[Faces Servlet]] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: org.jboss.seam.InstantiationException: Could not instantiate Seam component: org.jboss.seam.core.ConversationIdGenerator
at org.jboss.seam.Component.newInstance(Component.java:2106) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1988) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1950) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1944) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1939) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.core.ConversationIdGenerator.instance(ConversationIdGenerator.java:24) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.util.Id.nextId(Id.java:10) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.core.Manager.generateInitialConversationId(Manager.java:659) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.faces.FacesManager.generateInitialConversationId(FacesManager.java:122) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.core.Manager.initializeTemporaryConversation(Manager.java:651) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.endWebRequestAfterException(ExceptionFilter.java:102) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:70) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206) [richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar:3.3.3.Final]
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290) [richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar:3.3.3.Final]
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388) [richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar:3.3.3.Final]
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515) [richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar:3.3.3.Final]
at org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:58) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
....

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: by java.lang.ClassFormatError: Arguments can't fit into locals in class file org/jboss/seam/core/ConversationIdGenerator_$$_javassist_1
at org.jboss.seam.util.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:190) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.Component.createProxyFactory(Component.java:2388) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.Component.getProxyFactory(Component.java:1480) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.Component.wrap(Component.java:1471) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.Component.instantiateJavaBean(Component.java:1409) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.Component.instantiate(Component.java:1326) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.seam.Component.newInstance(Component.java:2084) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
... 38 more

Caused by: javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.ClassFormatError: Arguments can't fit into locals in class file org/jboss/seam/core/ConversationIdGenerator_$$_javassist_1
at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:170) [javassist-3.18.1-GA-redhat-1.jar:3.18.1-GA-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.seam.util.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:186) [jboss-seam-2.1.1.GA.jar:2.1.1.GA]
... 44 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Arguments can't fit into locals in class file org/jboss/seam/core/ConversationIdGenerator_$$_javassist_1
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.7.0_11]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_11]
at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass2(FactoryHelper.java:182) [javassist-3.18.1-GA-redhat-1.jar:3.18.1-GA-redhat-1]
at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:164) [javassist-3.18.1-GA-redhat-1.jar:3.18.1-GA-redhat-1]
... 45 more
```

Can anyone please help me to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue through updated the javassist jar file from the version 3.18.1 to 3.6.0.

Jboss eap 6.3 server using javassist-3.18.1-GA-redhat-1.jar, but my application supports javassist-3.6.0.GA.jar

Because of the jar miss match I have received the classFormatError "javassist-3.6.0.GA.jar".